# If a standard or VF page action causes a trigger to fire, does the trigger execute in the system context?

Tags: trigger, sharing

Assuming that the trigger only instantiates classes that are marked as `without sharing` does that trigger fire in the system context for:

1. A standard object page
2. A VF page with a controller or extension marked as `with sharing`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trigger runs in [system context for both cases](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm), the with sharing only impacts record visibility, i.e. FLS etc will be ignored in both cases

> If a class is not declared as either with or without sharing, the
>   current sharing rules remain in effect. This means that if the class
>   is called by a class that has sharing enforced, then sharing is
>   enforced for the called class.

I believe StandardController references are still an exception and still operate in user mode

so `stdController.save()` in a without sharing controller extension would still error, if the user did not having Edit access on the record.